# Are Darpa Robotic Challenge Simulator and DRC-based Gazebo a part of ROS Fuerte?

Tags: gazebo, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are the DRC Simulator and DRCGazebo updates a part of ROS Fuerte?

When updates to DRC Gazebo and the DRC Simulator occur, are both DRC Gazebo and the DRC simulator also updated for ROS Fuerte?

If so, how do I update the latest Gazebo and simulator in Fuerte?

It would be nice to use the latest Gazebo and simulator advances in the ROS environment.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51733/are-darpa-robotic-challenge-simulator-and-drc-based-gazebo-a-part-of-ros-fuerte?/) by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a question on the gazebosim site that seems to be similar.  I would suggest taking a look at it here: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/246/drcsim-which-ros-versions-will-be-supported/

---

Originally posted by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) with karma: 586 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2